# Multiple Containers interaction in single touch move

Tags: gesture, flutter

Playing around with Flutter, I am trying to interact in one touch move with multiple elements. However my gesture is triggered only in first Container.

Is there any way to do this using GestureDetector or Listener classes?

I mean, is there any better solution than set Listener on parent element and calculate if current touch pointer position is between coordinates of child elements I want to recognize touch event?

Here is an example of code to illustrate the issue I am dealing with.
Swiping horizontaly, I would like to select all TapBox elements in Row.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Swipe select',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Swipe select'),
    );
  }
}

class TapBox extends StatefulWidget {
  TapBox({Key key, this.bgColor}) : super(key: key);
  Color bgColor;

  @override
  _TapBoxState createState() => new _TapBoxState();
}

class _TapBoxState extends State<TapBox> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Padding(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
      child: new GestureDetector(
        onPanUpdate: ((e) {
          this.setState(() {
            widget.bgColor = Colors.blueAccent;
          });
        }),
        onPanStart: ((e) {
          this.setState(() {
            widget.bgColor = Colors.blueAccent;
          });
        }),
        child: new Container(
          width: 50.0,
          height: 200.0,
          color: widget.bgColor,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new TapBox(bgColor: Colors.grey),
            new TapBox(bgColor: Colors.grey),
            new TapBox(bgColor: Colors.grey),
            new TapBox(bgColor: Colors.grey),
            new TapBox(bgColor: Colors.grey),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: So basically, change all `TapBox` to `blueAccent` on click of `Any` TabBox. Am i right?